# XSLT concatenate input from several nodes in a single output

Tags: sorting, xslt, concatenation

I'm trying to work out a transformation that will process an input with several Flights with Departure and Arrival into a single output with the complete route for the flights.

Input is as follows:

```
<FlightTrip>
   <flights>
      <departureAirport>
         <airportCode>LocB</airportCode>
      </departureAirport>
      <departureTime>2013-03-28T10:00:00.000</departureTime>
      <arrivalAirport>
         <airportCode>LocC</airportCode>
      </arrivalAirport>
   </flights>
   <flights>
      <departureAirport>
         <airportCode>LocA</airportCode>
      </departureAirport>
      <departureTime>2013-03-27T15:00:00.000</departureTime>
      <arrivalAirport>
         <airportCode>LocB</airportCode>
      </arrivalAirport>
   </flights>
   <flights>
      <departureAirport>
         <airportCode>LocC</airportCode>
      </departureAirport>
      <departureTime>2013-03-30T14:00:00.000</departureTime>
      <arrivalAirport>
         <airportCode>LocD</airportCode>
      </arrivalAirport>
   </flights>
</FlightTrip>
```

The desired output would be this:

```
<FullTrip>LocA LocB LocC LocD</FullTrip>
```

I've tried to use foreach inside the output variable but I can't get it right. I also need to sort the input based on the departure date as the Flights can be in a different order (as per the sample input).

Any ideas of how to achieve this?

Thanks a lot!

Bruno

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="FlightTrip">
        <FullTrip>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="flights">
                <xsl:sort select="departureTime"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </FullTrip>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="flights">
        <xsl:value-of select="departureAirport/airportCode"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:if test="position()=last()">
            <xsl:value-of select="arrivalAirport/airportCode"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Will produce:

```
<FullTrip>LocA LocB LocC LocD</FullTrip>
```

**[Working example](http://xsltransform.net/jyyiVhf)**

Comment: Thank you Joepie.
The solution didn't run in my case though; I'm using Oracle BPM and it says I can only use <xsl:template match="/"> or <xsl:template name="">

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Joepie for the enlightenment. I had to modify it a bit to get it to work in my environment, ended up using foreach as below:

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="locations">
        <xsl:for-each select="/FlightTrip/flights">
          <xsl:sort select="departureTime" order="ascending" data-type="text"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(departureAirport/airportCode,' - ')"/>
            <xsl:if test="position() = last()">
                <xsl:value-of select="arrivalAirport/airportCode"/>
            </xsl:if>
         </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>

      <FullTrip>
          <xsl:value-of select="$locations"/>
      </FullTrip>

  </xsl:template>
```

When applied to the example produces the output below:

```
<FullTrip>LocA - LocB - LocC - LocD</FullTrip>
```

Thanks again!